Which technique to use for models that include Likert-scale items?
I have three or more independent variables (a Likert scale was used) and GWA as my dependent variable, to see what variables are influencing student compliance with respect to a school's grade retention policy. Is multiple regression applicable to this? Also, what are my other options for testing?

If you are open to doing a Bayesian analysis, take a look at this paper: Bürkner, P.-C. and Charpentier, E. (2020), Modelling monotonic effects of ordinal predictors in Bayesian regression models. Br J Math Stat Psychol, 73: 420-451. https://doi.org/10.1111/bmsp.12195. You can get the preprint version here. The case study models a subjective pain measure (the outcome variable) as a function of the difficulty to perform a physical activity as measured on a 5-point scale (from "no problem" to "complete problem").

Methods to Use
I'm not sure what you mean by factors being Likert-scale. Factors or categorical variables are typically on the nominal scale, but perhaps that was just some imprecision of wording.
With respect to which method to use, linear regression comes with the assumption that the variables are measured with perfect precision (Kline, 2023, p.104). With single-item Likert-scale responses, one can get away with including it alone into a regression (see Lucas & Donnellan, 2012 and Wanous et al., 1997 for examples). But that comes with the assumption that your scale measures your construct well (without much error) and consequently doesn't require additional items to tease apart how the construct works. The problem with this assumption is that we can't actually check how reliable the measure is without many studies that support using it. Thus it is much more common in the social sciences to take the sum or mean of multiple Likert-scale items to achieve something that has more content validity, has as "smoothed over" error, and is generally more sensitive to the construct being measured.
Now if one makes a composite of items like prescribed above, this requires formally checking the reliability (with Cronbach's alpha or preferably something like McDonald's omega coefficient, see Flora, 2020 for details). If the reliability is poor, including these composite measures into the model contributes to attenuation bias (the coefficients of the regression become biased, see Sengewald & Pohl, 2019). Thus if reliability is exceptional, we can still get away with regression, but if it is not, we should instead turn to a factor analytic approach such as structural equation modeling (SEM), where the latent construct you are trying to measure is fit to a model that incorporates the uncertainty of the estimates Kline (2023) provides an exceptional introduction to this topic if you are curious about it.
References

Flora, D. B. (2020). Your coefficient alpha is probably wrong, but which coefficient omega is right? A tutorial on using R to obtain better reliability estimates. Advances in Methods and Practices in Psychological Science, 3(4), 484–501. https://doi.org/10.1177/2515245920951747
Kline, R. B. (2023). Principles and practice of structural equation modeling (5th ed.). The Guilford Press.
Lucas, R. E., & Donnellan, M. B. (2012). Estimating the reliability of single-item life satisfaction measures: Results from four national panel studies. Social Indicators Research, 105(3), 323–331. https://doi.org/10.1007/s11205-011-9783-z
Sengewald, M.-A., & Pohl, S. (2019). Compensation and amplification of attenuation bias in causal effect estimates. Psychometrika, 84(2), 589–610. https://doi.org/10.1007/s11336-019-09665-6
Wanous, J. P., Reichers, A. E., & Hudy, M. J. (1997). Overall job satisfaction: How good are single-item measures? Journal of Applied Psychology, 82(2), 247–252.

